# Ceate repository for android on tfs

Tags: tfs, repository

I want to upload android source code on TFS using visual studio and my server side is written using C#
how to create repository for android on TFS

Comment: Any help please

Comment: If Andy-MSFT hasn't answered this could you provide more information in your question? For example: What IDE are you using for the Android source code (Android Studio, Eclipse, VS with Xamarin, ...)? Are you using VS Team Explorer to connect to TFS? Are you using Git or TFVC in TFS? Are you getting some sort of error message? Screen shots might also be helpful.

Comment: i have uploaded code on git repository  ,but the problem face to me now is it  applicable to upload srs documnets on git project or the  version control project must be team foundation instead of git ???

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE1:**

Please read Get Started documents first:

- [Get Started with Git and Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart)
- [Get Started with TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs)

---

**UPDATE2:**

If you just want to isolate the documents from the source code, you can create a new folder under the project, or create a new branch to store the documents, of cause you can create another repository, it's based on your requirements. Please see [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files) for details.

---

Do you have any special requirements? If not, nothing different with other projects. Assuming you are using TFVC, just try following below steps:

1. [Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer)
2. [Create a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project)
3. [Add repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project#add-repositories)
4. [Configure your workspace and check in the source files/changes.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#configure-your-workspace)

You can create the repository individually for client and server projects as needed.

If you just want to upload the existing source code to TFS, you just need to [Put an existing solution under version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/set-up-team-foundation-version-control-your-dev-machine#put-an-existing-solution-under-version-control)

Please see the [overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/overview) documents for more information.

If you are using Android Studio, you can install the [Team Services Plugin](https://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/AndroidStudioPlugin/Index) for Android Studio with Git repositories used. See [here](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/androidstudio) fro more info.

Comment: Thanks , for reply .now i can create local git repositary on visual studio how can i push it on tfs.second what is the next step to upload andoroid source code on tfs

Comment: @user1321920 I think you need to read the TFVC and Git documents first. For Git, you need to clone the repository, then commit your work, then sync, please see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart

Comment: @user1321920 Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: first , i create new project of type git and upload  my android code on this repository and working fine  , but the problem face me now  is it applicable to upload srs documents or other documents likes kick off project on git project or not ?

Comment: @user1321920 If the documents need to be in source control, then you can add/copy them to the repository, then vs will detect the added files in Changes. then commit > push them to remote repo.

Comment: I need the documents isloated from source code in seprate folder ,is that need to create another repositary in same project to upload only document on it

Comment: @user1321920 If just isolate the documents from the source code, you can create a new folder under the project, or create a new branch to store the documents, of cause you can create another repository, it's based on your requirements. Please see this article https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files